# How can I repeatedly launch an iPhone app from within one LLDB session?

Tags: lldb

I want to launch an app repeatedly with as little delay as possible in between runs, and do it from the command line. With both `ios-deploy` and `xcrun xctrace`, it takes about 15 seconds per run due to LLDB setup. Instead, I'd like to run it multiple times from within the same LLDB session (or use some other, faster solution). With ios-deploy launching a debugserver on the device, I've tried as such:

```
platform select remote-ios --sysroot /path/to/sysroot
process connect process connect connect://127.0.0.1:<port of debugserver>
target create "/local/path/to/App.app
```

However, after the last line I get an error message, "the platform is not currently connected".

Does anyone know how to launch an iPhone app multiple times from within the same LLDB session, or else some other faster way of launching an app repeatedly from the command line for a non-jailbroken device?

Answer (score 0):

`process connect` connects to a running debugserver on the remote device.  Some agent has to start up that debugserver and tell you want port it is listening on for `process connect` to work.

lldb doesn't actually know how to start up debugserver on remote iOS devices. That's something Xcode is responsible for, and then it tells lldb how to connect to the debugserver remotely.  But Xcode doesn't have API's to allow other clients to create debugservers on a remote iOS device.  I don't think you can do what you are trying to do.

What you want at a high level is some kind of "repeat N times" or "repeat till failure" behavior that could reuse the same lldb session.  Might be worth filing an Enhancement Request with http://bugs.apple.com asking for that.

Comment: I can start a debug server already via `ios-deploy`

Comment: Then you can write a python-based command that runs ios-deploy using Python's subprocess to start a debugserver on the remote, then uses SBTarget.ConnectRemote to attach to whatever port ios-deploy gave you to talk to that debugserver, then calls `process launch` to launch the process on the device.  Then just use that new command wherever you would have used "run"...